# Limit directory size in a Docker container

Tags: linux, directory, docker, limit, size

I have a web application in a Docker container. I need to limit maximum size of some of its directories. When I was not using Docker, I just created disk partitions of the limit size and put those directories to there. But since Docker seems to share disk partitions with the external system (the output of `lsblk` command inside the container is exactly the same as if performed outside), this approach is not possible.

How to solve this? Is there possibly a tool which check the size of a directory and denies the permission to write if the size extends the limit?

Comment: What about a limited partition like you already did, create desired folders there and mount them with e.g. `--volume /limitedpartition/var:/var:rw`?

Comment: that is for sure a possibility, but it violates the principle of keeping the deployment as simple as possible - something else needs to be done besides just running the docker image and I would like to avoid this